# Matching 2 names with ids

Tags: sql

I have 2 table.

**principal table** (people names with id):

```
 ID     NAME
 14     Person1
 29     Person2
```

**substitution table** (matching 2 people with principal id):

```
SUB1ID   SUB2ID
 14       29
```

I want to select the names in the substitution table like:

```
SUB1ID   NAME1     SUB2ID   NAME2
14       Person1   29       Person2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s1.SUB1ID,p1.Name,s1.SUB2ID,p2.name FROM principal p1
INNER JOIN substitution s1
ON p1.id=s1.SUB1ID
INNER JOIN principal p2
ON p2.id=s1.SUB2ID
```

Output

```
SUB1ID  Name    SUB2ID  name
14      Person1 29      Person2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    T.Sub1ID,
    P1.Name,
    T.Sub2ID,
    P2.Name
FROM
    Substitutions T
    INNER JOIN Princial P1 ON T.Sub1ID = P1.ID
    INNER JOIN Princial P2 ON T.Sub2ID = P2.ID
```